# How to write to margin in beamer?

Tags: beamer

I'm creating a `beamer` presentation using the Bergen style. As you can see in the example below there is a margin to the left that is used in Titleframe, the ToC and the `enumerate` and `itemize` environments. (Who? and When? is written to the margin.) I would like to access this margin manually. For example I'd like to be able to put the caption of an image in this margin. Otherwise I end up with a lot of blank space on a lot of frames.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks for your help!

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Bergen}
\usecolortheme{beetle}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\usepackage{tikz}

\author{author}
\title{MWE}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{section1}

\subsection{subsection1.1}
\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}
\item abcde
\item fghij
\item klmno
\end{itemize}
\begin{enumerate}
\item 12345
\item 67890
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\section{section2}
\subsection{subsection2.1}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{caption in the margin would be nice}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you can access the left margin with `\llap`.  In the case of `figure` captions, you have to avoid the `figure` environment, so that you can use `\captionof{figure}{}`, which can be placed in an `\llap`ped `\parbox`.

I have a fuzzy memory of someone warning against the use of the `caption` package (required for `\captionof`) in conjunction with `beamer`.  I can't speak to that admonition.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Bergen}
\usecolortheme{beetle}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{caption,stackengine}
\usepackage{tikz}

\author{author}
\title{MWE}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{section1}

\subsection{subsection1.1}
\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}
\item abcde
\item fghij
\item klmno
\end{itemize}
\begin{enumerate}
\item 12345
\item 67890
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\section{section2}
\subsection{subsection2.1}
%\begin{figure}
\smash{\llap{\parbox[t]{1.1in}{\captionof{figure}{%
  caption in the margin would be nice}}~~~}}
\belowbaseline[-\ht\strutbox]{\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (0,2) -- (2,2) -- (2,0) -- (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}}
%\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]